# Draw a tree/graph with wpf? [Using Canvas or what?]

Tags: wpf, graph, canvas, tree

i would like to build my own control with a datasource. This control should draw a simple binary tree :-)

What should i use as drawing base? Should i use a canvas or should i override some paint event method like onRender()?

The nodes should be some sort of usercontrol.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a container should be driven by the features you need.
Use a Canvas when you need absolute positioning.

However, the control could be an ItemsControl and you could use the Canvas in the ItemsPanel. After all the Canvas is just for display/arranging.

You can use the ItemsControlTemplate to set the DataTemplate for the nodes.

Have a look at [hierarchical datatemplates at the end of this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Perhaps all you have to do is create a template for the treeview control and subclass the treeview control to override the Arrange pass.

You can also learn from [this approach by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/WPF/AdvancedCustomTreeViewLyt.aspx)

Comment: Yes you can do that but be aware that your code is now dependent on the existance of a canvas (with a specific name) in the template. In other words: a designer can't simply replace the template.

Comment: In my control template i placed a canvas and i use this canvas for arranging some contentpresenters and displaying some lines.

i also have a datasource property... but how can i build a generic property?

you can build a tree with any object which has a list as member with objects of the same type.

class person {

list childs;

}

i would like that my control detects tree datasources and draws the tree... i dont would like to use one type of datasource or introduce a interface...

what should i do?

Comment: I added to my answer. My guess is you could simply create a subclass of the TreeView control.

Comment: Sry i'm not able to follow you. I have my code that draws a tree graph. I use a node class to calc x and y values. The arrangement depends on the data... its not possible to change the panel... there is a sample tree http://www.yworks.com/img/net40/net_collapsible_tree.png

Comment: I assumed the control was positioning its children and that in fact your control is the same as a TreeView Control with just a different layout. So I would subclass the TreeViewcontrol to arrange the child controls/nodes and draw the arrows and add a control template containing a canvas to accomodate the positioning.

Comment: Can you post a simple example please? i dont get it.

Comment: I added an extra reference to a post that solves the problem by using a Template.

Comment: This article doesn't help me :-( i would like to create a new control as custom control lib. i need some more information about howto use hierarchical datatemplates and item generator in my custom control. (I don't mean to apply datatemplates on a treeview!!!)

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help with that. The only way I can think of is to use Reflector on the TreeView to see how it is generating the children and using the hierarchical datatemplates.

Comment: Ok thanks! I would be very cool if any object is a node and all nodes to gether build up a real visual tree... you could set a datatemplate for the nodes and a style... i don't have any hint to implement this... => my problem is not to draw tree graph form a valid datasource... my proble is to build a cool wpf control :-) can someone help me?